# Mac slow to wake up

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-silicon

so recently i bought an M1 Macbook Pro, I started using it regularly and there seems to be no problem whatsoever, but then 5 days ago it started to wake up very slowly. Sometime it could take my mac 30 seconds just to show the log in screen. Anybody know whats wrong with my mac?

Comment: Is it connected to an external hard disk (or any external devices)?

Comment: I agree with @mmmmmm ... Some time ago, I had a wake-up with long delay; turned out the Mac was waiting for a volume that was no longer connected.

Comment: no its not connected to anything

Comment: sometimes the screen just went black a couple seconds before the log in menu appears